# data conversion to double

Tags: c#, type-conversion, sqldatareader

Can someone tell me why this C# code

```
item.Price = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["Ar"]);
```

gives me an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The Price item is `double`, `rdr` is a `SqlDataReader` and `Ar` is a `float` type column of a table ... I thought that I should use `float` too in C# but I think that has other representation.

Can someone help me with this? I am trying to get some prices from the DB but it's not working. If you have any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like item.Price isn't a double. Can you add in the declaration for Price so we can see how it's set up?

Comment: Why is this tagged as sql?  Is there a query involved?

Comment: item.Price is a Int. Change it's type and it will work

Comment: "the Price item is double" are you _totally sure_?

Comment: i fell stupid ... i changed up the items ... sorry to bother you all ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that item.Price is defined as an integer.

Comment: i fell stupid ... i changed up the items ... sorry to bother you all ....

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is that the Convert.ToDouble() method is seeing your DBs float as a double, yet the expected parameter is an int (seeing as you wouldnt convert from double to double). Have you tried this?:

```
item.Price = (double)rdr["Ar"];
```

Comment: Read the error message `Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to **'int'**. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Agreed, an sql column data type mismatch would not cause a compile-time exception. The only logical conclusion is that the property `item.Price` is an int.